# как из строки (JSON) вытянуть токен ? PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Вот так она выглядит в браузере

нужно вытянуть value  access_token

```
string(168) "{"access_token":"1000.5e0f81d80e89af94137ac96a70344b23.a69702c6ba1efc98e226c93a1eb97408","api_domain":"https://www.zohoapis.eu","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если эта строка у вас в переменной `$string`, то так:

```
$token = json_decode($string, true)['access_token'];
```